# Group By Title in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, view

I am having issue with group by Title column.
There is Title(1) in the view and when I click to small arrow to drop down nothing shows up. But if I upload something, it comes twice.
[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me for this.

Comment: can you remove the grouping from the list altogether from the document library? How does it look like?

Comment: After removing grouping, it looks all fine. No issues.

Comment: Can you show us how you set up the Grouping? I.E. the view settings UI